# replace argument with an IP address

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have a list of about 50 systems with unique ip addresses that i need to regularly ssh into.  I know these systems by a four digit alphanumeric number, but am constantly having to look up the ip addresses whenever I ssh into them. I would like to create a bash script that contains a list of all of the IP addresses for each machine, and i can type:

```
ssh_script aa11
```

and it executes:

```
ssh 111.222.333.444
```

Follow up question: some of the systems require a port # but i would still like to just type ssh_script bb22 and it does

```
ssh 333.444.555.666 -p 4444
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use DNS or /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be easy as such.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
port=22
case $1 in
 aa11) host=111.222.333.444;;
 bb22) host=333.444.555.666
    port=4444;;
 *) echo "$0: host $1 unknown" >&2
    exit 2;;
esac
exec ssh -p "$port" "$host"
```

(This script uses no Bash features, so I put `#!/bin/sh`. It should work with Bash as well, of course.)

But probably a better solution is to configure this in your `~/.ssh/config` instead; then it will also work transparently for `scp` and programs which invoke `ssh` internally, like for example `git`.

```
Host aa11
  Hostname 111.222.333.444

Host bb22
  Hostname 333.444.555.666
  Port 4444
```

See the [ssh_config](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) manual page for details about this file.

You can combine the two;

```sh
#!/bin/sh

test -e ~/.ssh/config_too || cat <<\: >~/.ssh/config_too
Host aa11
  Hostname 111.222.333.444

Host bb22
  Hostname 333.444.555.666
  Port 4444
:
exec ssh -F ~/.ssh/config_too "$@"
```

(Not all `sh` instances necessarily support `~` even though it's now mandated by POSIX; maybe switch to `"$HOME"/.ssh/config_too` if you have an oldish `sh` on some systems.)

Comment: imho ssh config file is far superior to anything else.  `-F` can specify an alternate config file when ssh is executed, if you feel that this information doesn't belong in a default config - for example, if you want to distribute it independently. (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html)

Comment: works like a charm thank you @tripleee!  i need to be able to run this from different systems and not able to edit the config on all, so this standalone script is just what i needed.

Comment: If you can save a standalone script, you can save an alternate configuration file to specify with `-F`, as suggested by Daniel Farrell.